# Initialize jquery again after replacing list with ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, smarty, prestashop

I have a Prestashop module to display a list of latest products from different product categories. On top of the list of products are menu links like: ALL, CATEGORY 1, CATEGORY 2, CATEGORY 3, etc. When page opens, it displays "All" the latest products. But when I click on Category 1 for instance, it uses Ajax to load only products belonging to the category I clicked.

I implemented this jquery plugin on the module - https://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/03/19/thumbnail-grid-with-expanding-preview/.

The main jquery file grid.js is loaded before the end of the `</body>` and initialize by adding the code below before the end of the `</body>` too:

```
<script>
   $(function() {
      Grid.init();
   });  
</script>
```

This works well when the page is just opened. But when any of the category links are clicked. The products for that category are loaded but the grid jquery expanding grid does not work again.

In the js file for the module loaded within the `<head>` of the page, I noticed that the ajax call for the categories are made with the code below:

```
$(document).on('click','#list-category-new-product li a',function(e){
        $('#blocknewproducts1_reload').addClass('active').prepend($('.newproduct_ajax_loader').html());
        $('#blocknewproducts1').css('opacity', '0.7');
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" },
            url: baseDir + 'modules/blocknewproducts1/newproduct_ajax.php',
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            dataType : "json",
            data: 'ajax_new_product=1&p=1&id_category='+$(this).attr('data-id'),
            success: function(jsonData,textStatus,jqXHR)
            {
                $('#blocknewproducts1').html('');
                $('#blocknewproducts1').html(jsonData.blocknewproduct);
                $('#blocknewproducts1').css('opacity', '1');
            }
        });
    });
```

I don't know much about jquery so I am wondering how I can get the expanding preview to work when the various categories are clicked and products loaded via ajax.

Answer (score 0):

the

```
<script>
$(function() {
      Grid.init();
   }); 
</script>
```

is a one off function, you need to call it again in your success call like so

```
$(document).on('click','#list-category-new-product li a',function(e){
        $('#blocknewproducts1_reload').addClass('active').prepend($('.newproduct_ajax_loader').html());
        $('#blocknewproducts1').css('opacity', '0.7');
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" },
            url: baseDir + 'modules/blocknewproducts1/newproduct_ajax.php',
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            dataType : "json",
            data: 'ajax_new_product=1&p=1&id_category='+$(this).attr('data-id'),
            success: function(jsonData,textStatus,jqXHR)
            {
                $('#blocknewproducts1').html('');
                $('#blocknewproducts1').html(jsonData.blocknewproduct);
                $('#blocknewproducts1').css('opacity', '1');
                $(function() {
                    Grid.init();
                }); 
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I have actually tried this but it did not work. I guess it is because the code for the success call is included in the head and not before the end of the body where the expanding preview code is expected to be place. I also copied the whole success call code to the end of the body adding the function like you did above but it did not work also.

Comment: This may sound dumb but will it be possible to insert the code you suggested above in such a way that that aspect of it will only be fired at the end of the body like the original code?

Comment: nope, the events you need to re trigger need to be placed in the success callback of the code, you could try using a function and then call it

Comment: I am sorry you have gone beyond my skill level. I am still stuck with this.

Comment: Yes. I am not familiar with jquery that much, except to just copy the codes and put them in the right places